# Why call setResult in BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

in the C2DM sample code from google, when a notification recived in BroadcastReceiver they call :

`setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null /* data */, null /* extra */);`

I didnt know what the setResult do. this is what they say in Android docs :

> Change all of the result data returned from this broadcasts; only
>   works with broadcasts sent through Context.sendOrderedBroadcast. All
>   current result data is replaced by the value given to this method.

Can somebody explain what they mean and why i need to call it?

Complete code :

```
public class C2DMBaseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        C2DMReceiver.runIntentInService();
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null /* data */, null /* extra */);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `setResult(...)` method in `BroadcastReceiver`, its more than anything for tracking purposes.

If you are familiarised with the `Activity`'s method `setResult(...)`, you can think of this method in broadcast in the same way. But instead of getting a callback method like `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` in the case of activities, broadcast `setResult(...)` method is used to keep track of the results of the broadcasts in a certain order, that's why the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#setResult(int,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) says:

> Only works with broadcasts sent through Context.sendOrderedBroadcast. All current result data is replaced by the value given to this method.

Which means that you can make use of the methods `getResultCode()`, `getResultData()` or `getResultExtras()` to know how things went during the execution of the `onReceive(Context, Intent)` method in all the different `BroadcastReceiver`s registered to handle your broadcast. So you can know the result of the code execution in the previous `BroadcastReceiver`  called before the one currently executed along all the receivers.

It says only [Context.sendOrderedBroadcast()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendOrderedBroadcast(android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.String)) because a regular call to `sendBroadcast(...)` method might not wait for 1 receiver to complete its execution before starting another thread to execute code in other receiver listening the same intent as well.

Answer (score -1):

setResult() method sets the result to be used in the calling Intent. Suppose you have called your custom receiver from any other activity using startActivityForResult(intent,code) then in the onActivityResult() method in the same activity you can use the results obtained from the called activity, only if there is a setResult() method in the another activity. It's just a way to call an activity via intent and get results back to the same activity.

Answer (score -1):

Example: In your main activity, you start an activity with a request code. Your main waits a result at the end of this activity.

```
startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode);
```

At the end of his working, the new activity sets a result code (work A done, work B done... etc) and a intent(not necessary), and finishes himself with call to finish().

```
void setResult (int resultCode, Intent data);
```

Your main activity gets this result with the funciton onActivityResult(). It checks the request code to know which work has been executed and to get the result / state of this work. (and the data, if there were waited a intent. but the data can also be the result code).

```
void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data);
```

Hope I helped you.